# remove selection of checkbox not working

Tags: jquery

```
function removeSelection(button) {
    $('#a').bind('click', function() {
        if($(button).hasClass('checked')) { 
            alert("a");
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'false');
            $(button).removeClass("checked");
        }
        else {
            alert("b");
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
            $(button).addClass("checked");
        }
    }); 
}
```

Behavior:

```
first click - Alert('b')
second click  Alert('a') Alert('b')
third click   Alert('a') Alert('b') Alert('a')
```

What should be:

```
first click - Alert('b')
second click  Alert('a') 
third click   Alert('b')
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please post the HTML you're using this with.

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/ for posting

Comment: `.attr('checked', 'false');`: It does not matter which value the `checked` attribute has, the mere *existence* of the attribute indicates that the element is checked.

Comment: you are binding inside a function - so each time the function is ran you are binding a new click event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) if you are using jQuery 1.9. and use true and false for check and uncheck.

```
function removeSelection(button) {
    $('#a').bind('click', function() {
        if($(button).hasClass('checked')) { 
            alert("a");
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $(button).removeClass("checked");
        }
        else {
            alert("b");
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            $(button).addClass("checked");
        }
    }); 
}
```

> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked
>   attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and
>   should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The
>   checked attribute value does not change with the state of the
>   checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to use the property [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the attribute "checked" from the tag. It's not a matter of css.

http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/